# Swift 4.2 Alamofire : Extra argument 'method' in call

Tags: alamofire, xcode10, ios12, swift4.2

I have updated my codes to Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2 , i have got this error. extra arguments.
I tried all solutions available but they are perhaps for older versions of swift. I am usign alamofire version :Alamofire 4.7.3 
and here is my code :

```
func callRemoveUserApi() {
        let token = SharedManager.getAuthenticationToken()
        MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
        let headers = [
            "token": token
        ]
        let manager = SharedManager.sharedInstance
        let user = manager.getUpCurrentUser()
        var params = [String:String]()
        params  = [
            "id": user.removed_member!.description,
            "userpath":self.selectedUser.userpath!,
            "path":user.path!
        ]


        Alamofire.request(removeMember, method:.put, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoder.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            print("Request  \(String(describing: response.request))")
            print("RESPONSE \(String(describing: response.result.value))")
            print("RESPONSE \(response.result)")
            print("RESPONSE \(response)")
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                var tempResponseDict = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                // var array = tempResponseDict.object(forKey: "data") as! NSArray
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("callMatchesApi"), object: nil)
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                break
            case .failure( _):
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                break

            }
        }
    }
```

**Solution :** 
convert JSONEncoder.default to  JSONEncoding.default
and Alamofire call will be.

```
Alamofire.request(mobileInfo, method:.put, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
```

Comment: I have faced this issue before and I have passed header as "HTTPHeaders" type and it's working for me.plz try this hope it will work for you. :)

Comment: i am sending a string token say "jk345l4kl5kl345kl" as header. Can show your code . as answer?

Comment: Sure, bro, I will.

Answer (score 0):

Header Declaration :

```
 var header : [String:String]?
```

Adding values to Header :

```
   header = [AppConstant.Content:AppConstant.ContentType,
                      AppConstant.Authorization : UserDefaults.standard.secretObject(forKey: AppConstant.AuthToken) as! String]
```

Alamofire method :

```
Alamofire.request(mobileInfo, method:.put, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
```

Hope this will work for you, Good Luck.. :)

Comment: i am doing the same. let headers = [
            "token": token
        ] .token value is a string. can you show how you are using headers in Alamofire method.

Comment: Plz, try this let headers = [ "token": token as! String] because it is considering token as any

Comment: var headers = [String:String]()
         headers = [
            "token": token ]   i have chaged it to this. but i still get the same error.extra argument.

Comment: 'Alamofire.request(appConstant.WebService_URL+strURL, method: .get, parameters: params, headers: self.header).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in'

Comment: Try to pass : headers as! [String : String ] or as! HTTPHeaders

Comment: i had solved it , see answer below my question.anyways thanks